# Reading erroneous data form csv file using read_csv from pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas, anaconda

I am trying to read data from a huge csv file I have. I is showing me this error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 13: invalid start byte`. Is there any way to just skip through the lines that cause this exception to be thrown? From the millions of lines these are just a handful and I can't manually delete them. I tried adding error_bad_lines=False, but that did not solve the problem. I am using Python 3.6.1 that I got through Anaconda 4.4.0. I am also using a Mac if that helps. Please help me I am new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that there are some non-ascii characters in your file that cannot be decoded. Pandas accepts an encoding as an argument for read_csv (if that helps):

```
my_file = pd.read_csv('Path/to/file.csv', encoding = 'encoding')
```

The default encoding is None, which is why you might be getting those errors.[Here is a link to the standard Python encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) - Try "ISO-8859-1" (aka 'latin1') or maybe 'utf8' to start.

Pandas does allow you to specify rows to skip when reading a csv, but you would need to know the index of those rows, which in your case would be very difficult.

Comment: Thanks I was able to read the csv file. However, for every black cell from the file, the DataFrame says nan. I want to construct an equality statement like `if df.col[0] == nan` then something. But that says nan is not defined. What can I put in the equality statement?

Comment: Do you want to remove rows that are "nan"? If you want to do that, you can do something like 

`df = df[df.Column_name == "nan"]`

Should work, or 
`df = df[df['Column_name'].str.compare("nan")]`

If you want to find the cell with the value, do something like

`if df.iat[i, j] == "nan"` with indices i and j